# I would like to know more about the risks of not verifying the GPG KEY

Tags: google-chrome, security, yum, amazon-linux

I would like to know more about the risks of not verifying the GPG KEY.

Now I can't install chrome from yum on Amazon Linux2.

```
yum install -y google-chrome-stable
```

gpg key verification fails.

```
Failing package is: google-chrome-stable-114.0.5735.90-1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

I checked and found that the latest version of chrome is signed with a subkey of the gpg key,
I've gotten to the point where I can't verify with the old package management system.

Nothing has been announced on google official, and I can't find any plans to fix it.

So here's the question.

I know that you can install it by downloading the chrome rpm directly or by setting yum's gpgcheck to 0.

Are there any possible security risks in this case?
the risk i thought was

1. Even if the chrome package is tampered with on the site hosting the chrome rpm, you won't notice
2. If there is DNS poisoning, it downloads fake chrome from a fake site

Please let me know if any of the above is incorrect or if there are other risks.